# Swipe refresh to be called only when user swipes for it, not when user reaches top of list

Tags: android, android-support-library, swiperefreshlayout

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic

Referring to the sample above. The swipe refresh is calling when user scrolls up reaches top of the list. What i want is to call swipe refresh only when user specially swipes for it. Not calling swipe refresh when user is scrolling up and reached top end.

When i am using the lib below, i get what i want. But i m facing some issues with this lib so i didnt want to use it.
github.com/baoyongzhang/android-PullRefreshLayout

Here is the video clip of what i dont want:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2g3SV1qz5TUFdZZ1FUNmxzU1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you test out the implement beside just reading it? I don't recall swipe refresh get trigger when i reach the top of the list.

Comment: Sir the swipe to refresh is triggering even in this sample when i reach top of this list.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve just to edit the sample or implement the swiperefresh in your project

Comment: code snippet please..

Comment: ok wait for few minutes

Comment: added a video clip of what is not required.Thanks

Comment: Bro..  That how swipe to refresh work. After you reach the top of the list if you still scrolling that the event trigger swipe to refresh. It wasn't trigger once you reach the top of the list view it trigger once you reach the top of the list view but still keep scrolling it more further. What else did you expect?

Comment: @teckwei i want the swipe refresh to trigger only user specially swipes for it not when we r scrolling up a list...... The problem with this situation is when the list is just larger than the screen by 1 or one element or so. When user scrolls up after scrolling down then swipe refresh triggers which feels awkward

Comment: @AyushGupta then u have no choice to create your own swipe refresh layout. It is hard though. By the way try to not use listview with mutiple layout instead of multiple view in a screen.

Comment: @teckwei Bad luck... i didnt want to do that but thats the only way...Thanks...Actually the lib that i mentioned worked fine but its giving some glitches in animation of refreshing

Comment: @AyushGupta you could study the lib and change some part of its code to make it not glitches just remember everything is in program

Comment: @teckwei As you already mentioned "It is hard though"......hhahahah its not easy doing that.....Thanks for your comments

Comment: @AyushGupta did you solve this i'm also looking for similar solution. some time onRefresh() not triggered when recycler is scrolled to top.

Answer (score 1):

now begin with the xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/contact_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

in the above code there is a listview inside swipeRefreshLayout, put it inside the layour of your activity

then in your activity declare it by this just inside the activity class

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
ListView listView;
```

then inside of onCreate method assign the xml code to it

```
     swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_swipe_refresh);
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_listView);
```

then put your adapter to listview and set onrefreshlistener to the swiperefreshlayout by this

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new 

    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                   //call a method here which make a webservice call or what ever you are using to put data inside the listview then set adapter and call  

swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: i have done the implementation correctly....... please see the video clip once. I dont want this swipe refresh triggring when reaching top of list

Answer (score 1):

```
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            switch (scrollState) {
                case SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                    //scroll was stopped, let's show search bar again
                    break;
                case SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
                    //user is scrolling, let's hide search bar
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (firstVisibleItem > 0) {
                //user scrolled down, first element is hidden
                //you can add the swipe trigger statement anywhere
            }
            else {//else
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "List Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    swipe.setRefreshing(false); //Refresh view Close
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Just add the swipe Refresh Layout surrounding the List View With an Id and u can use the above code to do action. As u wished it works when the user wants to swipe. Not when the listView hits the top

Comment: Its not working as the way it should. Please check the video clip that i added...Thanks

Comment: The property of the swipe is that it starts when it hits the top of the list and u have reached the top of the list (Source: Video).  so it gets pulled down for a refresh. This Same property can be seen in Gmail app.

Comment: Agree......But the problem arises when u have a list which is greater than screen by one or two element. When user is at the bottom of the list, ad when he tries to scroll up immediately the refresh triggers which feels awkward

Comment: I guess that u are using an emulator to run your app. when u the list from top to bottom. it just hits the top and doesn't trigger the swipe. after getting to the top u have to make an another pull to trigger the swipe. U can get the difference when u are using it on the phone and not in emulator.

Comment: running on my phone android: 7.1.1

Comment: with this, u can control the trigger if the swipe statement. It's generally used for the get the position and perform a various action.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tried to solve your problem

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/infoText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pull Down to Refresh" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="424dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRefreshListener {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeView;

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private String[] LIST_ITEM_TEXT_CITIES = { "Los Angeles", "Chicago",
            "Indianapolis", "San Francisco", "Oklahoma City", "Washington" };

    private String[] LIST_ITEM_TEXT_MORE_CITIES = { "Phoenix", "San Antonio",
            "San Jose", "Nashville", "Las Vegas", "Virginia Beach" };

    private List<String> cityList;

    // variable to toggle city values on refresh
    boolean refreshToggle = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_view);
        swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeView.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW,
                Color.CYAN, Color.BLACK);
        swipeView.setDistanceToTriggerSync(20);// in dips
        swipeView.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);// LARGE also can be used

        cityList = Arrays.asList(LIST_ITEM_TEXT_CITIES);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.list_item, cityList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

            if (refreshToggle) {
                refreshToggle = false;
                cityList = Arrays.asList(LIST_ITEM_TEXT_MORE_CITIES);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.list_item, cityList);
            } else {
                refreshToggle = true;
                cityList = Arrays.asList(LIST_ITEM_TEXT_CITIES);
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.list_item, cityList);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            swipeView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "city list refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 1000);
        };
    };

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        swipeView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```